# C# Parsing JSON Array(HTTPrequest Response) to display

Tags: c#, json, python-3.x, json-deserialization

Good day,

I am having with parsing JSON response. Let's say I have this JSON:

```
{
   "data": {
       "count" : 3,
       "innerData" : [
       {
           "dataInfo" : "heheh",
           "dataInfo2" : "hahah",
           "dataInfo3" : "huhuh"
       },
               {
           "dataInfo" : "jejej",
           "dataInfo2" : "jajaj",
           "dataInfo3" : "jujuj"
       },
               {
           "dataInfo" : "fefef",
           "dataInfo2" : "fafaf",
           "dataInfo3" : "fufuf"
       }
       ]
   }
}
```

Okay. So what if I want to just display the datas like "**dataInfo**" only..in Python, I can easily do it by doing this:

```
for x in response.json()['data']['innerData']
    print(x['dataInfo'])
```

That would display this:

```
>>> heheh
>>> jejej
>>> fefef
```

How can I do it in C#? I tried this: http://procbits.com/2011/08/11/fridaythe13th-the-best-json-parser-for-silverlight-and-net

But that only worked for non-array JSON..

Hope someone can guide me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Json.NET

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("1.json"));
foreach (JToken o in obj["data"]["innerData"] as JArray)
    Console.WriteLine(o["dataInfo"]);
```